# How to set onItemClickListener using SimpleCursorAdapter using android.R.id.list

Tags: android, sqlite, onitemclicklistener

Hi I am trying to implement `OnItemClickListener` using `android.R.id.list` which is inbuild list in android using `ListActivity`. Is there any other way so that i can use onItemclickLietener without placing `ListView` object in front of `OnItemClickListener`. Please suggest.

Also I wan to set delete and update method using longclick listener using Database "update and delete " methods. So please help me out.

```
SimpleCursorAdapter adapter = new SimpleCursorAdapter(this, R.layout.file_row, c, from, to);
setListAdapter(adapter);
getnotelist.close();

WhatToPutHere?.setOnItemClickListener(new OnItemClickListener()
{
    @Override public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> arg0, View arg1,int position, long arg3)
    { 
        Toast.makeText(SuggestionActivity.this, "" + position, Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
    }
});
```

How to use this using `android.R.id.list` or How to get `ListView` in `ListActivity`

Answer (score 4, accepted):

if you are extending `ListActivity` then add `setOnItemClickListener` as:

```
getListView().setOnItemClickListener(new OnItemClickListener() {
            public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> parent,
                                      View view,int position, long id) {

               // do your work here
        }
      });
```

You can get ListView as if extending ListActivity:

```
ListView listview = getListView();
```

or by using `android.R.id.list` as

```
ListView listview = (ListView)findViewById(android.R.id.list);
```

Comment: @Shweta: If this answer helped you, you can mark it as correct by clicking the tick at the left of the answer.

Comment: @Shweta : see my edit answer i have also included your last line answer

Comment: What to fill in public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> parent,
                                      View view,int position, long id) {
        }

Comment: @Shweta : onItemClick this method used for getting selected item from ListView when user click on it